# Raaspberry pi HMC5883l compass sensor outputs the same value all the time

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

When I first connected the compass sensor I accidentally connected 5v to ground, ground to SCL, SCL to SDA and SDA to DRDY. However when I corrected this and run the python program it has outputted a number. However the number does not change. Is there a chance that i have burned out the mocule? My code is:
    import smbus
    import time
    bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
    address = 0x1e

```
def bearing255():
        bear = bus.read_byte_data(address, 1)
        return bear

def bearing3599():
        bear1 = bus.read_byte_data(address, 2)
        bear2 = bus.read_byte_data(address, 3)
        bear = (bear1 << 8) + bear2
        bear = bear/10.0
        return bear

while True:
        bearing = bearing3599()
        bear255 = bearing255()
        print bearing
        print bear255
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Are you using Vcc = 5V or 3.3V? Keep in mind that the sensor works with Vin < 3.6

Comment: In the tutorial that i was doing this by it said 5v